# Firebase does not save userdata to Firestore after creating user with FirebaseAuthentication - Angular 9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have an **Angular 9** web app and so far I have made it work quite nicely with **Firestore**. I have a form for adding user which saves the user to **Firestore** correctly but without adding them to **Authenticated users**, the add feature will be removed when I fix the issue below.

*users.component.ts*:

```
this.userService.addUser(user);
```

and in the *userService* I call:

```
 async addUser(user: User) {
      await this.firestore.collection('users').doc(user.email).set(user);
 }
```

**The problem is** when I want to register a new user with **FirebaseAuthentication**, the user data does not get saved in **users** collection. When user clicks on **Register** in *register.component.ts* I call:

```
   register() {
        this.authenticationService
            .register(this.form.controls['email'].value, this.form.controls['password'].value)
            .then(() => {
                this.userService.addUser({
                    nickname: this.form.controls['nickname'].value,
                    email: this.form.controls['email'].value,
                    role: 'Customer',
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

The register method in *authenticationService.ts*:

```
    register(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.angularFireAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    }
```

I have tried different approaches, using Promises, async / await, calling directly from register method in *authenticationService.ts*, using collection('users').add instead of set, using uid I get as a response as document uid instead of email.

I'm inclined to think that there is some kind of rollback mechanism, since I have subscribed to data$:

```
this.firestore
    .collection<User>(this.path)
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        map((items) => {
            return items.map((item) => {
                const data = item.payload.doc.data() as User;

                return {
                    ...data,
                };
            });
        })
    )
    .subscribe((data) => {
        this.users$.next(data);
    });
```

in *register.component.ts* ngOnInit:

```
  this.userService.users$.subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
  });
```

Which gave me some insight:

[image: Logs 4 then 3]

The subject triggers twice instantly, with 4 elements and then 3.

*users.component.ts*

```
constructor(private userService: UserService, public dialog: MatDialog) {}
```

*register.component.ts*

```
constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
) {}
```

Both components are part of the same module, but for some reason if I navigate to *users.component.ts* and then to *register.component.ts* saving user **works**! It gets added to both **Authenticated users** and **Firestore** users collection.

I am not getting any errors at any point.

So I really have no idea what might be causing it to behave differently, but I need it to work from *register.component.ts* without first navigating to *users.component.ts*.

EDIT:

My rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
    // all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // your app will lose access to your Firestore database
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 8, 6);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to manually add the created user to your collection.
After createUserWithEmailAndPassword() is sucesfully executed, you should call a custom function that get's the User Object and saves it to Firestore.
example:

```
register(email: string, password: string) {
    let rs = this.angularFireAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    return this.saveUser(rs.user)
}
saveUser(user){
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.angularFistore.doc(`users/${user.email}`);

    userRef.get().subscribe(snapDoc =>{
      if(!snapDoc.exists){
        const data; //Initialize 
        //do anything else
        return userRef.set(data, { merge: true })
      })
}
```

Comment: That seems to work. Care to give a more in detail explanation why does it require explicit call rather than simple add / set in then callback?

Answer (score 2):

If you see a rollback like this, it typically means that the server rejected the write operation based on the security rules you have specified for the database. So it seems like the user doesn't have permission to write.

You'll have to modify the [security rules of the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to [allow the user to write their profile data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication).

Comment: I have not put any rules in play yet, so I have the default rules with just the date as limit.

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 8, 6);
    }
  }
}